# What are flats looks like in compact locally symmetric spaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

For compact locally symmetric spaces, what are the flats looks like?
I assume the sectional curvatures are $\ge 0$ and the manifold is compact and locally symmetric. I want to know for any given point $p$, what does the maximum flat through $p$ looks like? 
Let's assume the rank is 2. Is it always an embedded torus?

Comment: Immersed, not necessarily embedded.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Do you mean, it is always an immersed torus?